# Eclipse "Apply Checkstyle fixes" or "Quick Fix" does nothing when trying to fix checkstyle errors in a java file

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have several checkstyle errors in a project I'm working on. I understand that there are two ways to fix checkstyle errors in eclipse with the checkstyle plugin which I mentioned in the title. Unfortunately, when I right-click on any error, "Quick Fix" is greyed out and right-clicking on a file then "Apply Checkstyle fixes" does nothing.

I've attempted to fix the issue from other stackexchange sources. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821683/eclipse-checkstyle) source claims that another quick-fix file needs to be made to actually fix the issues. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761639/eclipse-ide-quick-fix-all) source (among others) mentions nothing of the sort.

I'm using Luna release 4.4.0. Is there something I'm missing or is quick fix only available for very certain checkstyle errors?

Comment: Perhaps you could show an example or two, about errors you think should be fixable by Eclipse, but aren't.

Comment: Many of the errors are whitespace errors, i.e. "',' is not followed by whitespace", "':' is not preceded by whitespace", etc. Are these not fixable in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running Luna 4.4.2 and thought I had the same issue, but it seems that "Quick Fix" isn't available for all reported problems. It took me a moment to realize, because I right clicked on the file previously and did a "Apply Checkstyle Fixes", so the only items remaining are the ones check style doesn't fix automatically.